# Is there a mechanical benefit to playing an aspect mage?

Tags: shadowrun-sr5

An aspect mage can only cast spells **or** rituals **or** summon ghosts, **also** he or she can't travel in the astral realm.

Did I miss a benefit for choosing a limited mage?

Comment: I can't really tell you why you would play an aspected mage. For the role playing is a general answer for many people. Is your real question: "Is the aspected magician underpowered or does it have a less than obvious strength?"

Comment: I didn't intend that to be sarcastic. I just wanted to make it clear why I couldn't answer it. I apologise. Hey I Can Chan said it a lot better then me.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Good objection, i'll edit the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### It is a trade-off

The positive:

- At priority B they get a relative +1 to their Magic attribute, compared to "general" mages. They can easily raise their Magic to 6 with a Special Attribute Point from metatype. Thus their priority A selection is freed up for something else. (This is more significant if Sum-to-10 priority allocation is not allowed.)

or

- You can get access to magic with priority D.
- With only a B priority in magic and C in skills, they can start with a rank 6 magical Skill Group. To reach this level of proficiency in the same skills would require 10 or 12 skill points spent by a mage of similar Magic (or A in Skills).

The negative:

- Loss of Astral Projection.
- Loss of access to magical skills (may be irrelevant if you would/could not devote the skill points to them anyway)
- Having to buy all your spells/rituals/formulae with karma (immaterial if you are a conjurer)

Thus I would primarily recommend this option if you plan to rely mainly on conjuration, as you sacrifice very little. You can still have potent powers in the Astral via your spirits and you only lose access to skills you wouldn't learn and spells you wouldn't use. If you are an aspected sorcerer or enchanter, your versatility will be severely limited by not starting with 7 or 10 known spells, but that may be ok with you.

Another possibility is to grab this type with a low priority level (C or D) to add 1 or 2 magical tricks to your abilities relatively on the cheap side. Your dice pools may be a bit lower, but this is not necessarily an issue with certain spells or with summoning lower Force spirits.